# How to apply a specified function to multiple variables in a data frame?

Tags: r, function

I am quite new to writing functions and am working a generic function that is to be applied to several, but not all, rows in a data frame. The function is supposed to conditionally transform the values of these specified rows.

Example data: 
`df <- data.frame("Var1" = c(0:5), "Var2" = c(-5:0), "Var3" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0)`

```
> df
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    0   -5    0
2    1   -4    0
3    2   -3    0
4    3   -2    0
5    4   -1    0
6    5    0    0
```

Example function:

```
myFun <- function(x, na_value){
  x[x == na_value] <- NA
  x
}
```

Given that I want 0's to transform to NA for Var1 and Var 2 - but NOT Var3, I have written `df$Var1 <- myFun(df$Var1, 0)` and `df$Var2 <- myFun(df$Var2, 0)` - but there has got to be a simpler way of doing this?

What I evision is something like `myFun(Var1, Var2, 0)` that transforms the 0's in Var1 and Var2 to NA without having to repeat the code for both variables. The function is to be applied for multiple data frames with different variable names and different na_values which is why I have written it in the first place, and it works fine, but I would like to simplify even more.

Comment: Another posibility: `df[, c("Var1", "Var2")][df[, c("Var1", "Var2")] == 0] <- NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one single dataframe, `apply` is the standard way to do this. For example here:

```
df[ , -3] <- apply(df[ , -3], FUN = myFun, na_value = 0, MARGIN = 2)
df
```

I don't know if your other dataframes are formatted exactly in the same way, however. But you can combine an `apply` and a `lapply` (or `mapply`) to do this operation on all your dataframes.

**EDIT**: Here is a more general (and a little ugly or old-fashioned) solution with a `for` loop:

```
## Define a list of two dataframes:
df <- data.frame("Var1" = c(0:5), "Var2" = c(-5:0), "Var3" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
df2 <- data.frame("VarA" = c(0:5), "VarB" = c(-5:0), "VarC" = c(3,3,3,3,3,3))
my_list <- list(df, df2)
## Colnames to consider, and missing values indicator, for each dataframe:
na_values <- list(0, 3) # NA = 0 in the first one, NA = 3 in the second
cols <- list(c("Var1", "Var2"), c("VarA", "VarB"))
## Define an R function to replace a given character by "NA" in a dataframe:
replace_nas <- function(data, cols, na_value){
    data[ , cols] <- lapply(data[ , cols], FUN = function(x) {
        x[x == na_value] <- NA
        return(x)
    }
    )
    return(data)
}
## Do this operation for each dataframe in "my_list" with a for loop:
res_list <- list()
for (k in 1:length(my_list)) {
    res_list[[k]] <- replace_nas(my_list[[k]], cols[[k]], na_values[[k]])
}
res_list
```

Probably not optimal, but it works!

Comment: IMHO it's better to use `apply` for `array`s and `lapply` for `data.frame`s as the first will coerce your `data.frame` to a matrix.

Comment: Oops, you're right! :-) All columns were numeric here so it does not really matter, but this will be a serious problem in other situations.

Comment: Thanks, ```lapply``` works great for this simple example. Is there a way to identify the columns I want to apply the function by name instead of ```df[ , -3]```?

Comment: I edited my previous answer to propose an ugly solution!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for a simpler solution, you could just identify the cells that equal to zero, thereby excluding column 3, and set them to `NA` like so:

```
df[-3][df[-3] == 0] <- NA
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1   NA   -5    0
# 2    1   -4    0
# 3    2   -3    0
# 4    3   -2    0
# 5    4   -1    0
# 6    5   NA    0
```